# Images access in NAS on web application impossible

Tags: php, apache, nas, cifs

I can't understand my problem.
I want to use images on NAS (+25Go) to get them on two server (web server FreeBSD).

My steps:

1. Create et config NAS on OVH (NFS CIFS protocole). I choose this protocole because web user are not same on two server
2. Mount the foldel :

   ```
   mount_smbfs -I IP_NAS -u UserID -g GroupID -d 0755 -f 0644 //IP_NAS/zpool-id_medias/images_origin /path/to/webroot/images_origin
   ```
3. Create symlink :

   ```
   ln -s /path/to/nas/mount/images_origin /path/to/webroot/images_origin
   ```

I can have images in ftp and with php.
But I can't use `<img>`.

Files `.gif` et `.nimp` are copy `cp` from original file `.jpg`.
This file are copy on a physical folder `n°1`. You can see a test capture:
[image: Capture des test]
I can't understand, why `.nimp` file works fine.
Can you help me ?

Comment: I think you need to look up `Alias` in Apache

Comment: It's OK in all case with .nimp file. In case I don't use Alias but symlink, in case 3 et 4 I use. If I need Alias case 3 et 4 with .nimp file don't work.